# How to know if users in my application already sent payment in Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

Can someone give me an idea on how do I know or validate that the user on my application already paid using PayPal? I want in my user table to set the payment_veried = '1' if the user already paid. I tried to search on youtube but the tutorial is not applicable on returning USER_ID after PayPal already verified the payment.

Comment: This all depends on how you trigger the payment. PayPal can send you notifications to a callback URL for example. _“I tried to search on yotuube but the tutorial is not applicable”_ - then I would suggest you start reading the actual documentation. (Who would want to trust any website with payments in the first place, if the developer only watched YT videos? That sounds way too risky for my taste anyway.)

Comment: I mean I only want that I can send also a parameter of userId from my database into paypal and paypal will return also the userId so I can set payment_verified into '1' when paypal verified the payment. Or is there any other way that I can verify that its the userId that paid me? If email on my database from user and email from their paypal would be the same then there would be no problem to me. 

I like to query on my db "UPDATE tbl_userpayment set payment_verified = '1' where userId = :userId";

Comment: You probably sending and id to paypal to know which user paid, get success message from paypal response and do your update query  `"UPDATE tbl_userpayment set payment_verified = '1' where userId = :userId";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "custom" parameter/variable during the checkout process.

This "custom" parameter's value will be returned to you at the end of the checkout, and also via any Webhook event of PAYMENT CAPTURE if you have a need to implement that asynchronous service, and also IPN if you have a need to use that even older service.

---

I wouldn't necessarily recommend depending on asynchronous notifications when you could get an immediate synchronous notification from a server-side integration when you do the capture. Here is a demo pattern of the UI for that: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

The server side portion of that type of integration (particularly for the transaction set up and capture API calls) are discussed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

If you do choose to implement a server-side integration, then -- once everything is working for the happy path -- don't neglect to implement funding failure error handling: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/ ;  This will allow buyers to choose a different funding instrument if e.g. their first card is declined by the capture attempt